# How to change TextBox input language to hindi

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I am working on a website in which users should fill some fields in different languages. I don't want the users to change their writing language using Alt+Shift key combination but rather i want the input language to be changed automatically to English to Hindi. But I'm not able to find any right solution. Please provide me solution in which should be able to put hindi text in `HTML` Input Textbox as well as in `ASP` Textbox

Is there any way to do that?

You can show your demo here

JsFiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/CL4N3/)

Comment: you need to use font for that....

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-multi-lingual-site-with-localization

Comment: @C-link: Which font about you asking and where we apply

Comment: for the text editor the hindi font....

Comment: Do you want to users to see hindi text using an English (QWERTY) keyboard? Or is it that you cant see actual Hindi typed text?

Comment: @NewAmbition: No i dn't want any kind of editor

Answer (score 0):

use javascript to change user's kepresses to your desired language.

See [Online Hindi Editor | Write in Hindi](http://www.hindieditor.com) (here you can see the JavaScript in source code to find how they are converting English key presses to Hindi.

The only requirement is your client browser should support Unicode.

Comment: This is recommended if your user is using a QWERTY keyboard